# How to resolve Deleted merge conflict in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, tortoisegit

I am novice in Git and use TortoiseGit as Git client

I have a conflict.
I click edit conflict and see following:

[image]

Can you explain what will happen if I click on
1. Modified
2. Delete
3. Abort

P.S. Actually I want to merge local and remote branch

Answer (score 4):

A deleted merge conflict occurrs if at the same time a file is deleted on one branch and modified on another branch. In your case the file was deleted on the active branch and deleted on the branch you're trying to merge.

Now you have to decide how to go on:

- Mark the file as deleted and ignore changes to the file - or
- mark the file as still-important in order to be kept and, thus, mark it as modified.

So, if you click on

- Modified: The modified file will be used (in the working tree and index)
- Delete: The modified file is discarded and the file will be removed in the working tree and index
- Abort: The dialog will be closed and the conflict won't be resolved.

Comment: actually project structure was changed and this file was moved to another location

Comment: also When I click Modified or Delete - tortoise says that this file in conflict state still

Comment: Git does not track files by name, but only by content. Therefore, the detection algorithm might not properly detect the right file if it was changed too much. You can see the filename in question in the title of the dialog.

Comment: If it's not working, please file an issue at http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/ and provide some steps how to reproduce (or upload the repository in question if possible).

Comment: Please also make sure you're using the latest version of TortoiseGit.